# Sending a welcome email parse cloudcode with mailgun

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mailgun

I have a working mailgun server in my parse cloudcode for an iOS app. I have set up a series of emails to be triggered by status changes in the database. I have now set up a welcome email that was formerly hard coded into the app. I have it set up as an afterSave however during the app the user is saved more than once, causing the welcome to be triggered. Is there a way I can only send this out once, or do I have to make it specific to a new user registering in the function if that is possible. Thanks.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
 console.log("aftersave fired");

if(!request.user.existed()){
var email = "Hello and welcome";
var subject = "Welcome to W!";
 var recipient = request.user.get("email");

console.log(recipient);
Mailgun.sendEmail({
to: "@gmail.com",
from: "@gmail.com",
subject: subject,
text: email
}, {
success: function(httpResponse) {
 response.success();
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
response.success();
}
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as set a flag in a new column on the `User` class which indicates that they have been welcomed. When the user is saved, check that flag and decide wether to send or not (and update the flag).